# Can not resolve import android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat;

Tags: import, accessibility

**Can not resolve**

import android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Need Replace**

```
import android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat;
```

to

```
import androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat;
import androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat;
```